# In RSpec, how do I print a custom message when "expect to be true" fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using RSpec 3.2.0 and I have this test:

```
  it "has a webhook_payload method" do
    Project.subclasses.each { |project_class|
      expect(project_class.method_defined? :webhook_payload).to be true, "#{project_class} is a Project subclass that does not have a required 'webhook_payload' method defined."
    }
  end
```

When I run this, it gives me this error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(project_class.method_defined? :webhook_payload).to be true, "#{project_class} is a Project subclass that does not have a required 'webhook_payload' method defined."
 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

I found this documentation on how to use custom error messages, and unless I have a typo, I feel like I'm following the instructions correctly: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-2/docs/customized-message

How do I print a custom message when this test fails?

Also, I'm very new to ruby and rspec.  If there's a more idiomatic way to write this test, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It thinks your message is a second argument to the `be` method, instead of to the `to` method.

Wrap `true` in parentheses and it should work, or just use `be_true` as the other answer suggests.

```
expect(project_class.method_defined? :webhook_payload).to be(true), "#{project_class} is a Project subclass that does not have a required 'webhook_payload' method defined."
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be be_true

```
it "has a webhook_payload method" do
    Project.subclasses.each { |project_class|
        expect(project_class.method_defined? :webhook_payload).to be_true, "#{project_class} is a Project subclass that does not have a required 'webhook_payload' method defined."
    }
end
```